# Extract public key from certificate x509

Tags: javascript, x509certificate, public-key, x509certificate2

I am looking for a way to extract public key from certificate x509 (PEM format) in javascript like this one:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.cer -pubkey -noout > pub.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something that can parse ASN.1 structure. You could use [pkijs](https://pkijs.org/).

Demo can be found [here](https://pkijs.org/examples/X509_cert_complex_example.html)

Comment: I use function in https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509 I have A PEM format of certificate but I d'ont  know how can I extract  th public keys from it

Comment: it works . var cert = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(pem); Public Key to PEM: var pem = forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(cert.publicKey)                           thank you   for your reply

Answer (score 3):

```
var cert = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(pem); 
var pem = 
forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(cert.publicKey)
```

Thanks halloulaguesmi. This seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Deepak,  this is exactly what I wanted and worked perfectly... stack overflow doing my job for me!

Answer (score 0):

After Node.js v15.6.0, you could use [publicKey](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#x509publickey) of `X509Certificate` from `crypto` module to retrieve the public key.

If you want to export publicKey, the [`export`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#keyobjectexportoptions) could be used

> For public keys, the following encoding options can be used:
>
> - type:  Must be one of 'pkcs1' (RSA only) or 'spki'.
> - format:  Must be 'pem', 'der', or 'jwk'.

Sample codes

```
const crypto = require("crypto")

const cert = new crypto.X509Certificate("pem file content"))

console.log(cert.publicKey.export({"type": "pkcs1", "format": "jwk"}));
```