# How to Parse below data x509 certificate and get Public key from it in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I parse the x509 certificate below and extract the public key from it using JavaScript or Angular 2?

I'm getting this response from an API and I have to parse above mentioned code to extract public key in JavaScript

```
certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIFkTCCBHmgAwIBAgIEAOATLTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBkDELMAkGA1UEBhMC\n" +
                "SU4xKjAoBgNVBAoTIWVNdWRocmEgQ29uc3VtZXIgU2VydmljZXMgTGltaXRlZDEd\n" +
                "MBsGA1UECxMUQ2VydGlmeWluZyBBdXRob3JpdHkxNjA0BgNVBAMTLWUtTXVkaHJh\n" +
                "IFN1YiBDQSBmb3IgQ2xhc3MgMyBPcmdhbmlzYXRpb24gMjAxNDAeFw0xNzEwMzEx\n" +
                "MzQwNTNaFw0yMDEwMzAxMzQwNTNaMIG+MQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjEOMAwGA1UEChMF\n" +
                "VUlEQUkxGjAYBgNVBAsTEVRlY2hub2xvZ3kgQ2VudHJlMQ8wDQYDVQQREwY1NjAw\n" +
                "OTIxEjAQBgNVBAgTCUthcm5hdGFrYTFJMEcGA1UEBRNAODdiNzU2ZjQ5ZWZlY2Jh\n" +
                "MTczNzllOTY5N2JhMmNmMzFkYTdlOGY4NGE2ZThmNGRhOGQwNWIxODNmYjVkMWFk\n" +
                "OTETMBEGA1UEAxMKQW51cCBLdW1hcjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCC\n" +
                "AQoCggEBAOlums2zjLx4cBx7MJGSN2hunAo3wuRu9Tk5bSkstTmIo4/Som8st2H5\n" +
                "Zy9YBpWNuqkT29LCqtzvJKu1WLClnRyrIWuEVxCerdJCb9+PXjjZwdUIIrGMyo0r\n" +
                "UzysN62ybPhYeC1Ab+eQge9JEmQsdrJJ9Mya3A/9/FdVPRG3pIPu9tvodYedtt/I\n" +
                "lhhDzzC7wfKKHXDY8ydU06anf+StC3GPiroqNHVKOWTI3ZiYKk9Qxnw9lOc3w4Ty\n" +
                "fYSO/NR3/2OeFfjFva+uJrnm2rBZmlb+ScmIkuY13os7OFA9vjLPiGkjCOpAaQZD\n" +
                "g8JzHiDSrKc01icLc/To/Dl/dVaLM9cCAwEAAaOCAcEwggG9MCIGA1UdEQQbMBmB\n" +
                "F2FudXAua3VtYXJAdWlkYWkubmV0LmluMBMGA1UdIwQMMAqACEzRvSoRSATTMB0G\n" +
                "A1UdDgQWBBQtqQG/bJDE3ZRmfzxsgLEIcF7BfzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBSAwgYwG\n" +
                "A1UdIASBhDCBgTAtBgZggmRkAgMwIzAhBggrBgEFBQcCAjAVGhNDbGFzcyAzIENl\n" +
                "cnRpZmljYXRlMFAGB2CCZGQBCAIwRTBDBggrBgEFBQcCARY3aHR0cDovL3d3dy5l\n" +
                "LW11ZGhyYS5jb20vcmVwb3NpdG9yeS9jcHMvZS1NdWRocmFfQ1BTLnBkZjB7Bggr\n" +
                "BgEFBQcBAQRvMG0wJAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmUtbXVkaHJhLmNv\n" +
                "bTBFBggrBgEFBQcwAoY5aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lLW11ZGhyYS5jb20vcmVwb3NpdG9y\n" +
                "eS9jYWNlcnRzL0MzT1NDQTIwMTQuY3J0MEcGA1UdHwRAMD4wPKA6oDiGNmh0dHA6\n" +
                "Ly93d3cuZS1tdWRocmEuY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvY3Jscy9DM09TQ0EyMDE0LmNy\n" +
                "bDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAOVx0mfOydPPGd3YW5qd28pWRPR3uq9hANq4e\n" +
                "c/Fqe1xg3dzlKWBWcUOLQqKuD5DEb6MYYzBCMe7iinDDzTNQFQq1y5rO+GD4WxN/\n" +
                "7mDkMnpdUju+vKi7AEF2wuqZBuNoSvdRqsq7ZgzLZXrdYwYLXaxpxcQ0QlzhECdv\n" +
                "/K2AGf/wv8nh/BIckHZuJSs5MrCZtiKS84tpXHHHL/Cjd0y3UO+35VvxFOZ50BQr\n" +
                "i4XEIDYQd0liyHwTWkv7CoxTYHO9DPPttd1s9nsY1mHSGGWLWUoy3v1yc4iFaw28\n" +
                "GXUxpP5A9BfwWFbeqaHx8Tcn0x8YB1r/dAQlE0G/VTsEiugxig==\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Comment: Plz answer if any one done it using any library..i m using angular 2 for my hybrid mobile application

Comment: do you want to parse the certificate? or you have to other data to use this certificate?

Comment: i want to parse the above data  and extract public key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract public key from certificate x509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675333/extract-public-key-from-certificate-x509)

Comment: tried but not working